# Как убрать список в WPF приложении?

Tags: c#, wpf

При запуске окна появляется такая менюшка в форме, как её убрать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очень просто.

1. Нажмите на кнопку «Перейти к визуальному дереву» («Go to live visual tree»).

   [image: перейти к дереву]
2. Отожмите кнопку «Показывать средства разработки в приложении» («Show runtime tools in application»).

   [image: отожмите]